# Click button on web page (python, webscraping)

Tags: python, web-scraping

I have a problem with clicking the button while scraping.
For example on the web page https://kolesa.kz/a/show/95457776
there is a button to show phone number ("**Контакты продавца**"), just on the right side of +7 777

I tried using *method .click() of bs4* and I used div class of this button ("**offer__show-phone action-link showPhonesLink js__show-phones**"). But every time I got error that there is no such class name.

Maybe you know other methods of it?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

The issue occurs where you're trying to locate an element using multiple classes, this causes selenium to throw back an error, the below will locate and click the button:

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path = 'path_to_webdriver')
driver.get('https://kolesa.kz/a/show/95457776')

element = driver.find_element_by_class_name('showPhonesLink')

element.click()
```